# WPF How to call User Control Command from window Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, command

This is a Dejavù question, I've asked yesterday evening but probably I didn't post it correctly because the question is not on my profile. If you find it please don't kill me for the double question.

As stated in the Subject, I'm implementing for the first time in WPF a visual studio like interface, I've read on MSDN the command target and command source article but still I've not been able to find a good sample to explain me the following:
If I have my main window with the ribbon and the 4 crud base buttons, Insert, Delete, Save and Undo, then I have several user controls, one for each Table or group of related tables, and I put the Controls in a docking manager creating Tab Like objects in the Main Window, how do I Bind the Ribbon commands so that they are executed against the currently "focused" User control, the one the user is currently seeing? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Send Ribbon command to the right user control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942334/wpf-send-ribbon-command-to-the-right-user-control)

Answer (score 0):

I have came across the same situation and somehow managed to implement it. Below is my Idea.

1. Create a IBaseViewModel with Crud commands,
2. Write separate  classes inherited from from BaseViewModel, and make sure they are the DataContext for each UserControl.
3. Set Ribbon DataContext from DockingManager's Selected child (i ended up writing attached property for finding Selected child.)

Comment: I would recommend changing step 3 slightly. I am not a fan of swapping Datacontexts. Could cause weird issues if you forget that you are doing that (which i have done). If you already have to traverse the visual tree, i would just operate on the object. I would suggest:
3. Find the Selected Child, Check to see it's `DataContext` is a `BaseViewModel` (I would prefer to use an Interface, so `IBaseViewModel`). You can then just call the Base methods directly : `((IBaseViewModel)MySelectedView.DataContext).Create()`.
You could get much fancier. But I have done something like this before.